# Docker - Puppeteer require somethings and wont run

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer

I've created a container with Docker from a NodeJS app,
but when I try to run it the application will start but goes in error loop.

My Dockerfile contain

```
RUN npm install
```

but it continuously break on:

```
ERROR PuppeteerCrawler:PuppeteerPool: Browser launch failed {"id":12}
  Error: Could not find browser revision 756035. Run "npm install" or "yarn install" to download a browser binary
```

If i run Node main.js there are no problem.

```
//Dockerfile 
FROM apify/actor-node-basic
    
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm --quiet set progress=false \  && npm install --only=prod
--no-optional \  && echo "Installed NPM packages:" \  && npm list \  && echo "Node.js version:" \  && node --version \  && echo "NPM version:" \  && npm --version

COPY . ./

WORKDIR . 
USER node 

RUN npm install 
COPY --chown=node:node . . 
EXPOSE 8080 
CMD [ "node", "Worker.js" ]

// package.json
    {
        "name": "SoccerBrain",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "description": "This is an example of an Apify actor.",
        "dependencies": {
            "apify": "^0.21.0",
            "puppeteer": "^5.0.0",
            "rimraf": "^3.0.2"
        },
        "devDependencies": {},
        "scripts": {
            "start": "node Worker.js",
            "test": "echo \"Error: oops, the actor has no tests yet, sad!\" && exit 1"
        },
        "author": "It's not you it's me",
        "license": "ISC"
    }
```

what's append?

Comment: Show us the package.json file from which you are installing your dependencies please.

Comment: Could you share your docker file (completely)?

Comment: done, updated post